# Flowchart Formatting - corrections

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I am trying to come up with a flow chart as shown below:
[image]

I tried as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
\tikzset{process/.style= {draw, shape=rectangle, align=center}}

   \node [process] (a1) {Input color face image};
   \node [process, below = of a1] (a2) {Image decolorization};
   \node [process, right = of a1] (a3) {Face Detection};
   \node [process, below = of a2] (a4) {Image binarization};
   \node [process, below = of a3] (a5) {Facial feature \\ extraction};
   \node [process, left = of a5] (a6) {Create\\ region, \textit{R}, for\\ determining\\ threshold $\theta$};
   \node [process, below =of a4] (a7) {Repeat “region growing” \\ and set the traced pixels to \\ “0” until there is no\\  nonzero pixel within the \\ “seed moustache region”};
   \node [process, below =of a5] (a8) {Create “moustache \\ region” and “seed \\ moustache region” \\ for the region \\ following};
   \node [process, below =of a7] (a9) {Is the total size of the region \\ growing resulting regions larger \\ than a threshold?};
   \node [process, left =of a9] (a10) {Non- \\ moustache \\ face};
   \node [process, below =of a9] (a11) {Is the moustache \\ region classified as \\ moustache?};
   \node [process, right =of a11] (a12) {Texture- \\ moustache \\ AdaBoost \\ classifier};
   \node [process, below =of a11] (a13) {moustache face};

   \path[draw,->] (a1) edge (a2)
               (a1.east) -| (a3)
               (a2) edge (a4)
               (a3) edge (a5)
               (a5) edge (a6)
               (a4) edge (a7)
               (a5) edge (a8)
               (a6) edge (a4)
               (a7) edge (a9)
               (a8) edge (a7)
               (a9.west) |- (a10)
               (a9) edge (a11)
               (a11) edge (a10)
               (a12) edge (a11)
               (a11) edge (a13)
               ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I am getting:

[image]

Can someone please correct what I am doing wrong? Tried a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the nodes on a grid and specify how far apart they should be.  But most importantly, to create the chart the flow should not start at the top but work out from the center most portion.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes.geometric,calc}

\begin{document}

\def\aes{*1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={LaTeX[scale=1.25]}]
\tikzset{process/.style= {draw, shape=rectangle, align=center,on grid,minimum height=1.5\baselineskip,inner sep=6pt}}

   \node [process,text width=2.25cm]                           (a6)  {Create region, \textit{R}, for determining threshold $\theta$};
   \node [process, right = 3.5cm\aes of a6,text width=2.25cm]  (a5)  {Facial feature extraction} ;
   \node [process, above = 2cm\aes of a5]                      (a3)  {Face Detection};
   \node [process, left  = 4cm\aes of a6]                      (a4)  {Image binarization};
   \node [process, above = 2cm\aes of a4]                      (a2)  {Image decolorization};
   \node [process, above = 1.5cm\aes of a2]                    (a1)  {Input color face image};
   \node [process, below = 3cm\aes of a5,text width=3.00cm]    (a8)  {Create “moustache region” and “seed moustache region” for the region following};
   \node [process, left  = 5cm\aes of a8,text width=4.25cm]    (a7)  {Repeat “region growing” and set the traced pixels to “0” until there is no  nonzero pixel within the  “seed moustache region”};
   \node [process, below = 3cm\aes of a7,text width=5.00cm]    (a9)  {Is the total size of the region  growing resulting regions larger  than a threshold?};
   \node [process, below = 3cm\aes of a9,text width=3.00cm]    (a11) {Is the moustache  region classified as  moustache?};
   \node [process, left  = 4cm\aes of a11,text width=2.00cm]   (a10) {Non-moustache face};
   \node [process, right = 4cm\aes of a11,text width=2.00cm]   (a12) {Texture-moustache AdaBoost  classifier};
   \node [process, below = 2cm\aes of a11]                     (a13) {moustache face};

   \draw[->] ($(a4.south)!0.5!(a4.south east)$) -- (a7.north-|{$(a4.south)!0.5!(a4.south east)$});

   \path[draw,->] (a1)      edge (a2)
                  (a2)      edge (a4)
                  (a3)      edge (a5)
                  (a5)      edge (a6)
                  (a5)      edge (a8)
                  (a6)      edge (a4)
                  (a7)      edge (a9)
                  (a8)      edge (a7)
                  (a9)      edge  node [midway,right]  {Yes} (a11)
                  (a11)     edge  node [midway,above]  {No}  (a10)
                  (a12)     edge (a11)
                  (a11)     edge  node [midway,left]   {Yes} (a13)
               ;

  \draw[->] (a9.west) -|    node [pos=0.75,left] {Yes} (a10.north);
  \draw[->] (a1.east) -|   (a3.north);

%% to help place nodes and determine what the `text width` should be
%% \draw[help lines] (current bounding box.north west) grid (current bounding box.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There's no need to introduce new lines manually.  You can set the width of the text for each node using `text width`.  I've also set a `minimum height` to create a bit more of a uniform appearance to the boxes.

[image]

Comment: `\aes` is in there to scale things later:  it's not necessary (and probably considered sloppy by others).

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and for the explanation as well :)

Comment: @Ellett Why there is no arrow to "Face Detection" block (top right)?

Comment: And can I add a label to it as well?

Comment: No, I mean label for the flow chart. Like for a figure we use: \ref{fig.abc} at the bottom of the image figure

Comment: As a standalone, I assume you'll be importing the `pdf` of this.  You can import it into a `figure` environment, but that's not any area I have much expertise in.

Comment: any idea how to fit this in one complete A4 page? I tried last answer on following link, that says \usepackage{adjustbox}  but its not working!
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18515/fit-flowchart-into-one-page

Comment: The *disappearing* arrow didn't disappear.  It was never drawn because the arrow only goes on the end of the path which occurs when the second `-|` is encountered.  The arrows with the `edge`s are there because `edge`s are added after the main path has been drawn.  To get the arrows with the `-|` each needs to go in its own path.